# Como comparar Date com campo em MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

Sou iniciante em Java e tenho uma tabela em MySQL que possui um campo do tipo date e as datas estão armazenadas no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Agora preciso recuperar somente os registro cujo valor do campo data seja maior ou igual a data de hoje.

Estou tentando fazer o abaixo, mas não está funcionando:

```
Date dataHoje = new Date();
Query consulta = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Consulta c WHERE c.dtConsulta >= dataHoje");
```

Alguém poderia dar uma ajuda?

Desculpem-me se não postei o código por completo, mas segue abaixo:

```
public List<Consulta> listarDatasLivresParaMarcarConsultas(int mes, int ano){

    em.getTransaction().begin();

    Date dataHoje = new Date();

    Query consulta = em.createQuery("select c from Consulta c " +
            "left outer join fetch c.terapeuta t " + 
            "left outer join fetch c.cliente cl " + 
            "SUBSTRING(c.dtConsulta, 1, 4) = ?1 AND " + 
            "SUBSTRING(c.dtConsulta, 6, 2) = ?2 AND " +
            "c.dtConsulta >= dataHoje AND " +
            "c.cliente = null AND " +
            "c.statusConsulta = 'C'");

        consulta.setParameter(1, ano);
        consulta.setParameter(2, mes);

        List<Consulta> consultas = consulta.getResultList();

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        emf.close();

        return consultas;
    }
```

O usuário escolhe o mês e o ano através de componentes JMonthChooser e JYearChooser, que devolvem dois inteiros respectivamente.

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda!!!
Augusto

Comment: Olá Augusto seja bem vindo ao SOPT, editei sua pergunta para adicionar marcação nas partes de código, isso facilita a visualização da pergunta, e a vc receber melhores respostas, visite http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour para entender um pouco melhor do site.

Comment: Augusto, por favor complemente seu código. Por exemplo, como você está usando o `consulta.setParameter(...)` ? Pois seu erro pode estar na ultilização do JPA em si, e não do JPQL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso no própria consulta SQL, exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM consulta t
WHERE t.dtconsulta >= curdate();
```

**[Veja aqui um exemplo minimalista](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ccf6/1)**

Comment: Obrigado a todos pela ajuda! Consegui solucionar o problema utilizando a função do JPA CURRENT_DATE.